# Can't pass in values to a page I'm linking to in XAML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml

I have the following code set up in xaml:

```
<Setter Property="Source" Value="ResourceHttpHandler.aspx?rt=img"/>
```

My problem is in the httpresquest process event function this:

```
        HttpRequest request = _HttpContext.Request;
        string rt = request.QueryString["rt"];
```

Is resulting with 'rt' being null, QueryString is empty.

Any ideas why this is? I don't think I'm doing it wrong or anything...